# Uploading attachment using SOAP sends only 6 bytes?

Tags: soap, soapui, soap-client

I am uploading the file using soap request , to demo zephyr enterprise server. The problem , is only the few bytes (6 bytes against 488) are sent to the server. Tried it in both Soap UI and through Java code. The result is same. I had a doubt about the proxy configuration but it supports for manual file upload. Any inputs and suggestion to root cause the issue? I have posted an query in zephyr enterprise forum too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that you have to enable MTOM in the request properties (`Enable MTOM` -> True) of the SOAP UI in order the request to work properly and specify a valid ContentID in `cid:XXXXXX` form as the tag value.

[image: SOAP UI Request Properties tool window with MTOM Enabled and Forces]

P.S. If you want to send several files to CXF as different parts you will also likely need to uncheck `Disable multiparts` property.